# Remove shortcuts to switch virtual terminals on Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, console, virtual-consoles

When you are running Raspbian without graphics (GNU bash), only in bash mode, if you press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>... you switch from current `tty` to another.
How to make that if you press these shortcuts nothing happens? Not even switching, nothing.

Why do I need that? I have a Raspberry without screen launching a python script on launch that listen keyboard entry, I already catch all <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> etc. but the user can switch `tty` and then it's no more on the `tty1` with the script running.

Comment: There might be a better solution. However if not, you could redefine keys. Run `dumpkeys | grep -i console` to see what keys manage VT switching. Read also the `loadkeys` and `keymaps` manpage.

Comment: Hi, thanks to [this link](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlkeycodes.html) and also showkey I identified the correct `keycode` to disable... yet I don't understand how to disable them... I tested `keymaps alt keycode 105=` and many others in bash but none are working... Do you have a tips for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As VPfB says you can find all the key mappings that switch to the console eg with

```
dumpkeys | grep Console >/tmp/map
```

This gives a long list of keys eg:

```
altgr   keycode  59 = Console_13      
alt     keycode  59 = Console_1       
control alt     keycode  59 = Console_1       
altgr   keycode  60 = Console_14
```

Replace the `Console_*` part of these with `VoidSymbol`:

```
altgr   keycode  59 = VoidSymbol
alt     keycode  59 = VoidSymbol
control alt     keycode  59 = VoidSymbol
altgr   keycode  60 = VoidSymbol
```

and pass the new file back into `loadkeys` to change the mapping

```
sudo loadkeys /tmp/map
```

You could also try just reducing the number of VTs to 1, probably in `/etc/inittab` for rasbian, or use the keyboard in raw mode, which is not easy as you will then have to map the key scancodes yourself.